# How to get a comprehensive listing of all defined variables (and their values)?

Tags: elisp

How can one list all the globally defined variables (ideally with their global-scope values) for the current Emacs session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `describe-variable` and `obarray`, it seems that the following should give you what you want.

```
(defun global-bindings ()
  (let (res)
    (mapatoms (lambda (vv)
                (when (and (boundp vv)
                           (not (keywordp vv))
                           (get vv 'variable-documentation))
                  (push (cons vv (symbol-value vv)) res))))
    res))
```